# Как в grid работает свойство fit-content?

Tags: css, css3, css-grid

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(300px) minmax(auto, 600px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr, 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="">111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
  <div class="">1</div>
  <div class="">1</div>
  <div class="">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Параметр `grid` по своей сути - это двумерная сетка, представляющая собой табличную форму для работы с элементами, где есть количество столбцов и количество строк. 
Он используется для того, чтобы можно было конкретный элемент разместить в нужное место на странице, придерживаясь общей концепции табличного отображения.

При помощи параметров `grid` Вы можете перемещать и задавать элементы таким образом, чтобы это не нарушало необходимую структуру отображения. 
Как Вы знаете, при помощи параметров `grid` можно делать достаточно много потрясающих вариаций отображения, задавая ширину столбцов, высоту, возможность склейки нескольких ячеек и так далее.

Если же брать именно параметр `fit-content`, то его задача ограничить ширину отображаемого поля. 
Например, в случае использования `grid-template-columns` или `grid-template-rows` в своём стандартном значении они имеют параметр `auto auto`, что означает, что данные поля сетки будут подстраиваться под размер контента, который в них находится. 
Пример с использованием автоматического размера контента:

```css
    .grid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="">111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="">1fkdsjhfkl shfkjhdsk jfhsdkjhf</div>
    <div class="">1</div>
    <div class="">1</div>
</div>
```

В данном случае, размеры ячеек сетки задаются в соответсвии с размером текста, который в них находится. (Если текста больше. то колонка шире или выше соответственно)

Свойство `fit-content` позволяет, в случае необходимости задать минимальную длину ячейки, уже не полагаясь исключительно на размер контента внутри, но ограничивается указанным параметром в соответствии с длинной элементов к контенте.

Например, используя фиксированные параметры в `grid-template-columns:` например `grid-template-columns: auto 10px;` Находящиеся внутри объекты будут обрезаться ровно по указанному размеру в 10px.

Пример:

```css
    .grid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto 10px;
        grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="">111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="">1fkdsjhfkl shfkjhdsk jfhsdkjhf</div>
    <div class="">1</div>
    <div class="">1</div>
</div>
```

Используя же параметр `fit-content` размер ячейки будет стремиться к указанному в нём параметру, основываясь на длине элементов, находящихся в них. 
Если простыми словами, то он будет подстраиваться под размер слов до пробела, или элементов до разделения, но всегда будет стремиться к указанному размеру переданному в `fit-content`.
Например:

```css
    .grid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto fit-content(10px);
        grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="">111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="">1fkdsjhfkl shfkjhdsk jfhsdkjhf</div>
    <div class="">1</div>
    <div class="">1</div>
</div>
```

Как Вы видите, размер поля не составляет 10px, но всегда к нему стремится. 
В данном случае, параметр `fit-content` проверяет длину находящихся в них элементов и задаёт размер по самому длинному слову. 
Если же параметр будет ниже указанного размера, то он будет составлять именно столько, сколько указано в `fit-content`.
Пример (указан параметр в 100px для демонстрации):

```css
    .grid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto fit-content(100px);
        grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="">111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="">1fk dsj hfk l shf kjh dsk jfh sdk jhf</div>
    <div class="">1</div>
    <div class="">1</div>
</div>
```

В данном случае, размер колонки будет минимально - 100px.

Итоги:
Параметр `fit-content` при максимальном размере элементов в нём будет автоматически расширять размер колонки в соответствии с контентом (В отличии от фиксированных данных в `10px`), но минимальное значение, при элементах меньше, чем заданы в `fit-content` он будет их располагать их рядом таким образом, чтобы они главное помещались в том размере, который был задан в параметре.

Comment: fill-content(10px) позволяет указать минимальное значение но если контент больше 10px то  grid-template-columns будет расширяться до первого разделителя ( пробела )  правильно для себя сформулировал св-во fill-content ?

Comment: @Leks всё верно.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Отличный ответ Мне особенно понравился стиль изложения, - и не очень длинно и не очень кратко, ровно столько, сколько нужно для понимания, на мой взгляд важной темы в целом, как grid